# Bayesian probability on disease

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability

There is a rare disease that only happens to 1 out of 100,000 people. A test shows positive 99%
of times when applied to an ill patient and, 1% of times when applied to a healthy patient. Please
answer the following questions.

- What is the probability for you to have the disease given that your test result is positive?
- What is the probability for you to have the disease when you did two tests and both of them
  show positive? Assume that two tests are conducted independent.
- Assume that the patient keeps on trying the test, what is the minimum number of tests that
  the patient has to try to be 99% percent sure that he is actually ill? Assume that all tests are
  conducted independently.

$$
\Pr(D\mid +)=
{
\Pr(+\mid D)\Pr(D)
\over
(\Pr(+\mid D)\Pr(D)+\Pr(+\mid \bar D)\Pr(\bar D))
}
$$
On substituting we get approximately
$0.0989 %$
But for the second question if he/she tested positive for both times
The probability should increase of him having the disease
But when we multiply
$0.989\times 0.989=0.978$ is the probability he has the disease

Please help me where I am going wrong

Comment: Could you post your attempt at this problem please.

Comment: P(D)=1/(10^5)
P(+/D)=99/100
P(+/Dbar)=1/100

Comment: Thanks! Could you use the "Edit" button underneath the answer to put your attempt into the question?

Comment: P(d/+)=p(+/D)*Pr(D)/(pr(+/D)*p(D)+pr(+/Dbar)*pr(Dbar))
On substituting we get approximately
0.0989 %
But for second question if he is tested positive for both times
The probability should increase of him having disease
But when we multiply 
0.989*0.989=0.978 is the probability he is having the disease 
Please help where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for $P(D|{+})$ in the comments of about 0.1% is correct. But surely you know that multiplying two numbers less than 1 will give you another number which is less than either of them, so your method cannot be right.

We want $P(D|{+}{+})$, the probability of $D$ given two positive test results. You can use Bayes' theorem again to get
$$
P(D|{+}{+})={P({+}{+}|D)P(D)\over P({+}{+})}
$$
But we need to think about what the values of $P({+}{+}|D)$ and $P({+}{+})$ are. We're told that the results are independent, so $P({+}{+}|D)=P({+}|D)P({+}|D)$.

The value of $P({++})$ is given by
$$P({+}{+})= P({+}\mid D)^2P(D)+P({+}\mid\bar D)^2P(\bar D)
$$
since the tests are independent of each other, but conducted on the same person with the same chances of having or not having the disease.
So the answer is

$$
P(D|{+}{+})={P({+}|D)^2P(D)\over P(++)}
$$
You already have $P({+}|D)$ and $P(D)$ from your answer, and you can calculate $P({+}{+})$ as shown above, so just plug the values in. It comes out to about 9%.

Comment: No.  The tests are *conducted* independently, **but on the same person**. They should be considered to be *conditionally* independent given that person's disease status.  $$P({+}{+})= P({+}\mid D)^2P(D)+P({+}\mid\bar D)^2P(\bar D)\qquad \neq P({+})^2$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you. I've corrected the answer accordingly.